# В memo1 переносится только первые 2 строки

Tags: delphi-7

При переводе из edit в memo, переносятся только две первые строки, остальные не отображаются, что делать?

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

  memo1.Lines[0]:='                    Трубопроводный транспорт маловязких нефтей';
  form1.Memo1.Lines[1]:='Средневзвешенная темпиратура грунта вдоль трассы нефтепровода  '+edit9.Text;
  form1.Memo1.Lines[2]:='Рабочее давление на выходе головной насосной станции   '+edit5.Text;
  form1.Memo1.Lines[3]:='123';
  word:=CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  Word.Visible := false;
  Word.Documents.Add;
  word.Selection.Font.Name:='Times New Roman';
  word.Selection.Font.Size:='11';
  word.Selection.Font.Italic := true;
  word.Selection.TypeText(memo1.text);
  Word.Visible:=true;
end;
```

Comment: @d сергей d, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: а в Memo по факту все 4 строки есть? просто обновлять строки подобным образом - очень багоопасно. Я бы просто добавил в начало `Memo1.clear;` а строки добавлял через `Memo1.Add(..);`.

Но, скорее всего в данном случае даже Memo не нужно. Хватит обычной строки.

Comment: @d сергей d
У Вас ошибка в слове `темпИратура`

Answer (score 3):

У вас `Memo1.Lines.Count=2` (это если вы текст дефолтовый из него не удалили), изменение `Memo1.Lines[2]` и т.д. не приводит ни к чему. Ибо

```
procedure TMemoStrings.Put(Index: Integer; const S: string);
var
  SelStart: Integer;
begin
  SelStart := SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_LINEINDEX, Index, 0);
  if SelStart >= 0 then
  begin
    SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_SETSEL, SelStart, SelStart +
      SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_LINELENGTH, SelStart, 0));
    SendMessage(Memo.Handle, EM_REPLACESEL, 0, Longint(PChar(S)));
  end;
end;
```

Получается SelStart=-1, и код дальше не выполняется.

Правильно работать с TMemo действительно через Clear и Add. Через индекс - тут хорошо еще exception не вылез, а то со StringList'ом получили бы index out of bounds.